# Data type conversion in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a requirement where the target column data type is date(ex- 30-Apr-14 i.e DD-MON-YY).

In informatica the default data type is date/time. So the source is sending the date data in the format MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. So when I am trying to insert this data into target it rejects.

How do I convert this source data from date/time to date,so I can finally have the output as DD-MON-YY and will be able insert into target table.

Thanks!
Ashim

Comment: What is the error? Could you edit your question to include some code we could try to debug?

Comment: It does not error out. Informatica read the data from source , processes. everything good until the end. The process is successful but all the source data are rejected. As my target table allows null values for the date column, it just updates null. So basically nothing is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use TO_CHAR(fieldname,'DD-MON-YYYY')

Where fieldname is your current date port and the expression is in a string port which itself will write to your date column

Comment: It is also possible to override the default date string format at the session level (on the config or parameters tab... I forget) so that all dates in the session will be in that format (am not sure which you'd prefer)

Comment: TO_CHAR(fieldname,'DD-MON-YYYY')  worked. I created an additional port with string data type. Passed the value from port with data type date/time. Thank You so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`Date/time` datatype has no `format`. If you process your data as `date/time` and send it to target using `date`, the connector you're using does the job for you. (NOTE: it usually is a number that is then shown in some readable format)

So, either:

- your target is using `date` datatype (and no conversion is needed). In this case the error seems to have a different source, or
- your target does expect a format, as it's a string with some check constraint.

Make sure which scenario you're dealing with.